# jquery-1.9.1.js:4421 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /item/category/category_details/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement bootstrap tabulation menu and each tab is a new page

This is my java script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
                  $(this).tab('show');
              });
              $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
                  var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
                  var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
                  $(".act span").text(x);
                  $(".prev span").text(y);
              });
          });
      </script>
```

And this is my html for tabulation menu

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Material</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a  href="/item/material/material_details/7">BOM</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/item/category/category_details/7">Manufacture</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/item/material/material_details/7">Product</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/item/material/material_details/7">UOM</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And below the error I am getting each time I select a new tab and obviously my tab doesn't change to active. I assume I am trying to something that is not intended to work with direct links but should work only with divs on the same page. Is there is a way getting  of tabulation effect in this way without having separate active tab menu for every page?

```
jquery-1.9.1.js:4421 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /item/category/category_details/7
```

Comment: What server side language are you using for your templating engine?

Comment: Do a view source and check what you see for your tablulation code. Update your question with that details and there may lie your answer as well.

Comment: I am using Django for backend

Comment: I updated the tabulation html with view source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap tabs expect the `href` to be a hash](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) which is parsed as a selector, specifically an ID selector, by jQuery. That hash corresponds to the ID of the section to display. Your `href`s appear to be urls instead of hashes causing it to fail.

Comment: Thanks Joseph the Dreamer, this is what I suspected . Is there a way to use bootstrap tab to work with url without using a frame ? Or I just will have to use same tab on each page with different tab  active?

Comment: My limitation I have a lot of parameters in my urls of values with which I am filtering my data and with urls I am using to send users back to previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add how I solved my problem at the end .

I was able to achieve active tabs with links using few templates in Django and   by  avoiding JS script altogether  using this django snippet .

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2421/